# Rendering multiple components with condition

Tags: reactjs

I have an if-else-block in my render-function. I always get the error that my myattribute is an unresolved variable.

```
render: function() {
    return ({
        this.state.something.length ? (
             <h3>Selected products</h3>
             <Element myattribute={this.state.something}/>
        ) : ''
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is, you are returning more than one element if the condition is true, try this:

```
render() {
 return (
    <div>
      {
        this.state.something.length ? 
          <div>
             <h3>Selected products</h3>
             <Element myattribute={this.state.something}/>
          </div>
       : ''
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```